# Append variable to a file using groovy script

Tags: groovy

I need groovy commands to add variable value to a text file.

I will show example using shell script

```
rm -rf myfile.txt
$a="some value"
$b="one more value"
echo $a >> myfile.txt
echo $b >> myfile.txt
```

Liek that I need to do using groovy script. and each appended value should append line by line not in same line.

I am new to the groovy, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `append` method but remember about new line (`\n`):

```
def f = new File('lol')
f.delete()
f << "1\n"
f.text
f << "2\n"
f.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do:

```
def a = '1'
def b = '2'
new File('myfile.txt').with {
    delete()
    withWriter { w ->
        w.writeLine(a)
        w.writeLine(b)
    }
}
```